# Programmatically convert coverage file to coveragexml

Tags: c#, code-coverage

I am using Visual Studio to find code coverage. I have generated .coverage file and I can open it in Visual Studio. I want to convert it into .coveragexml file.
I am using `CoverageInfo, CoverageDS` classes. Here is the code I am trying:

```
CoverageInfo info = CoverageInfo.CreateFromFile(coverageFilePath, binaryPath,symbolPath);
CoverageDS dataSet = info.BuildDataSet();
dataSet.WriteXml(outfile);
```

Since the coverage file is large, the call to info.BuildDataSet gives out of memory exception. Is there any alternate way to get the coveragexml?

I referred to the MSDN blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phuene/archive/2009/12/01/programmatic-coverage-analysis-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx which also mentions this case. This article mentions about using `ICoverageModule` interface to get module by module information from the  `CoverageInfo` class. But how do I convert this module information into XML? The blog shows an example of how the module information can be parsed and printed. But I am looking for converting this into coveragexml file.

Answer (score 3):

I was running into the same `System.OutOfMemoryException` when calling `CoverageInfo.BuildDataSet(...)`. To work around the problem I changed the project to build as a 64 bit application which enables the process to use much much more memory. You will also need to reference the 64 bit versions of:

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Interop.dll

You can find these on a system that has TFS installed. Look in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server XX.0\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\Plugins`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late to the party...

But I've created a dotnet tool to convert `.coverage` files to `.coveragexml` files to support SonarCloud Code Coverage when using VSTest@2.

See this link for details : https://github.com/StefH/CoverageConverter